# I am trying to decode UTF-8 to String but some of the special characters are not getting decoded ( “ and ’ ) insted showing up as ? question mark

Tags: java, utf-8

Unable to decode `’` and `“` which is encoded with UTF-8.

Used below code :

```
String displayString = inItem.GetDisplayString();
displayString = new String(displayString.getBytes(), "UTF-8");
```

example `String` is as follows:

```
"Platinum Stars’ 4-0 ravishing of Black Leopards only but did Ajax a colossal"
```

Comment: Could you please add an example `String`?

Comment: example string is as follows:                                                                               Platinum Stars’ 4-0 ravishing of Black Leopards only but did Ajax a colossal

Comment: Either you string is not correct utf-8, or the way you output is wrong ie. your terminal is not able to show UNICODE characters correctly.

Comment: another string as follows:                                                                               “The job is not done yet.

Comment: I am able to decode by using follow process but it is affecting another place:             displayString = URLDecoder.decode(displayString, "UTF-8");

Comment: &#x2019; is showing while decoding

Comment: The codes you're showing don't make sense. You can't decode a String to String. You decode **bytes** to String. These attempts won't work. Please do things differently, and if you don't know how, describe the process from beginning to end.

Comment: The first displayString object is encoded string with UTF-8 and from that String i am trying to get byte array from that by displayString.getBytes() and passing it to String constructor and decode it and then after i am storing it back to displaystring.@kumesana

Comment: You have already a String. What's the point of this encoding/decoding dance that can only make things worse. We see what you are doing the question is "why?". What problem do you want to solve?

Comment: A Java `String` is a UTF-16 encoded string, it is NOT a UTF-8 encoded string. The ONLY way a Java `String` can hold UTF-8 data is if the UTF-8 octets are expanded **as-is** to 16-bit characters. In which case, `displayString.getBytes()` uses Java's default charset and is likely to lose those octets when encoding the characters to bytes. Try using `displayString.getBytes("ISO-8859-1")` instead to recover the original UTF-8 bytes, then you can decode them as UTF-8 into a proper `String`.

Comment: Please use the divide-and-conquer technique. First, what are the UTF-16 (`char`) values that `inItem.GetDisplayString()` returns and do you believe this is actually text or some sort of encoding or escaping? View it as a String in your debugger as well as the UTF-16 values as Java escapes. `inItem.GetDisplayString().chars().mapToObj(c -> String.format("\\u%04X", c)).forEach(System.out::print)`

Answer (score 1):

> `&#x2019;` is showing while decoding [with `URLDecoder.decode(displayString, "UTF-8");` while processing `“The job is not done yet.`]

That is perfectly normal.

The character `“` is the unicode LEFT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK (`U+2019`), and not the QUOTATION MARK U+0022 character. Specifically it is not an ASCII character, and for that reason, `URLDecoder.decode` translates it to its HTML entity representation.

For the `"’"` character, it is the RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK (`U+2019`). Here again it is outside of the ASCII range, and not all terminals can display it correctly. In particular, Windows console under the default code page 850 cannot.

And of course, as both have a unicode code above 255 that cannot be represented in Latin1 or ISO-8859-1...

Comment: what is the solution which i can use to decode the special characters which is encoded with UTF-8 can you please help me out.

Comment: @JalaSureshreddy: I'm afraid I cannot help you more. There is no magic in converting String to bytes and back again. It only make sense when the string was originally decoded with a wrong charset. If your terminal wrongly displays some characters, the problem generaly is that the charset declared to the Java program is not the charset that the terminal can process. It can only be solved by fixing an environment variable, the charset used by the terminal or both. But it should not involve modifications of the Java code.

Comment: do you know if there is an API to throw an Exception or have a different replacement instead of `?` thank you

Answer (score 0):

Now first: java String will use internally Unicode, hence that is not the problem.

You are seeing HTML entities like `&#x2019;`, which will stem from some conversion. It could be data from an HTML form where the form element did not have: `<form accept-charset="UTF-8">` or the page was not in UTF-8.

One might repair this. Either use apaches common with `EscapeUtils.unescapeHTML` or in java > 9:

```
s = s.replaceAll("\\&#(\\d{1,7}|x[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,6});",
        new String(new int[] {
            mr -> Integer.decode(mr.group(1).replace("x", "0x"))
        }, 0, 1));
```

Which will convert numerical (possibly hexadecimal) entities as Unicode value.

Before java 9:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\&#(\\d{1,7}|x[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,6});");
Matcher m = pattern.matcher(s);
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
while (m.find()) {
    m.appendReplacement(sb, new String(new int[] {
            mr -> Integer.decode(m.group(1).replace("x", "0x"))
        }, 0, 1));
}
m.appendTail(sb);
s = sb.toString();
```

Integer decode handles strings like decimal `64` (char `@`) or hexadecimal `0x52BA`.